# Face fill between edges is connecting to wrong edges

Tags: faces, edges, intersection

I have two parts (green and blue). I'm trying to fill the gap between them. In image 1 I have highlighted two edges where I want to fill with a face. I press F to fill, and get the results in images 2 and 3. Instead of a face between the edges I selected, I get 2 long faces (one is seen on the back side in image 3) extending across the whole gap and intersecting with other faces (see white arrows). This used to work, but now it's not working right. I reset to default settings and tried some of the clean-up functions, but that hasn't helped. Does anyone have an idea as to what's going on?
Thanks

Image 1:

[image: Prior to Face Fill]

Image 2:
[image: After Face Fill]

Image 3:
[image: After Face Fill, view from other side]

Comment: Can you share the file? My guess is that the horizontal edge is not that short (but extends to the left to the next vertex) than the image makes it believe you.